# Sublime text editor: Change plugin hotkey?

Tags: sublimetext2, sublimetext, sublimetext3, hotkeys, sublime-text-plugin

In Sublime Text 2 or 3 (I use both, and the answer is probably the same for both), how do you change the hotkey of an installed plugin/package? (on Windows or Linux / Ubuntu)

I already know how to change the key bindings of built-in Sublime commands (Preferences > Key Bindings). For instance, one binding I already have is:

```
{"keys": ["ctrl+super+b"], "command": "show_panel", "args": {"panel": "output.exec"}}
```

But in the case of a plugin, how do I know what string to use for "command"? Is there an easy way to find out what the "command" is for an arbitrary function in Sublime?

I would like a general answer that applies to any plugin one could install. Though as an example, today I'm trying to change the hotkey for a plugin called SimpleClone, which has assigned <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Right</kbd> to Split Right. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Right</kbd> is a rather poor hotkey choice by the maker of the plugin since it already has a use in the operating system: when typing it selects the word to the right. Hence I want to change the assigned key binding.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If plugin has some shortcuts defined, they will be in the `*.sublime-keymap` files. So if you want to find some shortcut I guess you could grep through all the `*.sublime-keymap` files in Packages directories, but if you roughly know which plugin uses that shortcut you want to change that shouldn't be necessary :)

For example the Emmet plugin has keybindings defined in: `Packages/Emmet/Default (Platform).sublime-keymap`.

You can copy the keybinding definitions from these files to your user keybindings file (`Packages/User/Default (platform).sublime-keymap`) and modify them as you want.

Comment: It was tricky finding the packages directory. On Windows I found it in `C:/Program Files/Sublime2/Data/Packages/SimpleClone`. On Ubuntu & Sublime 3 I found a directory here: `~/.config/sublime-text-3/Packages/User` but this DID NOT contain the plugin in question. I did a search for "*.sublime-keymap" files but that didn't help because, as it turns out, the packages are stored in compressed archives in `~/.config/sublime-text-3/Installed Packages/`. Extracting the files within `SimpleClone.sublime-package` gave me the keymap file I needed. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can open Packages list by pressing `Cmd-Shift-P` (on Windows should be `Ctrl-Shift-P`), choosing `Package Control: list packages` then select the package you neeed and press Enter. Sublime will open package directory where you can find all desired `*.sublime-keymap` files.

Answer (score 1):

You can do the following:

1. Go to "Menu->Preferences->Browse packages..."
2. Find the directory of the interested package.
3. Find file with ".sublime-commands" extension.
4. Get command name from file.
5. Use "Menu->Preferences->Key bindings" for add key binding.

Ex (StringUtilities):

```
[
    { "keys": ["ctrl+b"], "command": "convert_to_base64" },
    { "keys": ["ctrl+shift+b"], "command": "convert_from_base64" },
    { "keys": ["ctrl+u"], "command": "url_encode" },
    { "keys": ["ctrl+shift+u"], "command": "url_decode" }
]
```